# Windows Azure , How to make custom registration process in Android App

Tags: android, azure-storage

I am using windows azure services for my android app, In this windows azure provide authentication from Facebook, Google,Twitter etc.

But i want custom registration for user and when user successfully register in app then they can also log in with there user id and pass that they created at registration time.

How is it possible using windows azure in android app.

Comment: Yes ... it is possible.

Comment: how Jones may u explain it ?

Comment: This (http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Exploring_custom_identity_in_Mobile_Services_Day_12_.aspx) is a walkthrough of how to do it from iOS.  I'm working on an Android specific sample which I should have posted early this week.  I will come back and add a link to this an an answer once the Android version is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this sample which demonstrates how to handle custom auth on the server side and client side: http://chrisrisner.com/Authentication-with-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services.  This post covers the server side scripts and links to a separate article that walks through the Android client application.  The code for everything is available on GitHub as well.

Of note is that I used a slightly modified version of the Android SDK that I forked to provide support for retrying requests.  This is NOT NECESSARY for you to do custom auth though the code won't compile if you don't point at the updated SDK.  You can just rip out the code that handles the custom auth registration and logging in if you want.